# Building a custom menu or use a plugin?

Tags: theme-development, menus

I am currently building my first ever wordpress theme, making good progress so far.
The very last and possibly hardest part is the menu the client is thinking about.
What it should look like:

```
Menu 1      | > 
Menu 2      | > 
Menu 3      | >
```

Menu 1/2/3 will open the category page. The > will open the submenu for the element.
For example for clicking the > behind Menu 1 it should look like

```
< Menu 1      
  Post 1.1   
  Submenu 1.2   | >
  Submenu 1.3   | >
```

Menu 2 and Menu 3 will not be visible anymore.
Click on a submenu will open the page. Click on < Menu 1 will go back to the default menu.

I honestly have no idea how to start here and if it's possible I would go and use a plugin for this.
But all the menus I did find are not working as hoped.

Has anyone ever had the same problem or knows a menu that could work the way I am looking for?

EDIT:
I currently have prepared a simple menu, looking like this

```
Menu 1     | v
Menu 2     | v
Menu 3     | v
Menu 4     | v
```

On Click on Menu 1 v :

```
Menu 1     | ^
Submenu 1.1
Submenu 1.2
Submenu 1.3
Menu 2     | v
Menu 3     | v
```

EDIT 2:
I came pretty close to what I was looking for so far with the standard wp menu and some css and js enhancements.
Last problem is that I need to display only the last subcategory as a back link. And somehow that seems to be impossible with the nested structur of the wp default menu. This looks more or less like this:

```
<ul class="primary-menu">
<li>
    <a>Menu 1</a>

    <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>
        <a>Submenu 1.1</a>
        
        <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
            <a>Post 1.1.2</a>
        </li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    </ul>

</li>
</ul>
```

First you only see Menu 1. Click on it and you see Submenu 1.1 and above the link back to Menu 1.

```
< Menu 1
     Submenu 1.1 | >
```

So far so good.
Now if you click the link to submenu 1.1, it looks like

```
< Menu 1
< Submenu 1.1
      Post 1.1.2
```

But it should only display the latest/closest parent level.
Seems to be impossible to hide Menu 1, as Submenu 1.1. is part of the given structure. If I hide Menu 1, Submenu 1 and the link to post 1.1.2 are gone as well.

Therefor my question: is it possible, to change or adjust the whole nav code structure? Or do we always have to handle the code from wp here?

Comment: Create a simple WordPress menu from wp-admin as usual. Then we can achieve the same result using css and js. It will take me a while.

Comment: Yes, I have a simple menu at the moment, with default dropdowns instead of this "push and slide" thing. I'll add the layout to the question above

Comment: @Behemoth is correct about the process. Once you have your menu created on the back end, you can follow a tutorial like this to get started on the CSS/JS for the menu: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp

Comment: The link is superb, thank you! Just need to find out how to adjust the given WordPress nav so that it looks like my sample above at the end. Will try to do so tomorrow.

Comment: @Pixelsmith:  I have created my menu but the given structure does not work for the layout I want to achieve. For example, it does have multiple nested ULs here. And if I want to display the selected link of the sub-menu only, that's not possible (or at least: not without a hack). It always displays the parent link as well :-/ Can I change the menu structure as well?

Comment: @jonSnow I'm not quite following what you mean. Can you update your question with the new part of your question, including code so that I can see what you're talking about.

Comment: @Pixelsmith Sorry, you're right. It's getting more and more complicated! I have edited my question above to make more clear what I want to achieve and what my current problem is.

Comment: btw, we still have the option to use a plugin, if someone knows one that fits the requirements decribed above..